# React-Native flexWrap doesn't work with Text on Android

Tags: android, react-native, line-breaks, react-native-flexbox, react-native-text

There is a simple wrapper view, dynamic text on the left and a static green view on the right side. I'm trying to make it automatically **move static green view below** the Text by using `flexWrap` style **when the Text reaches 2 lines and becomes multiline**. When text fits one line - keep all at the same row.

```
   <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: 'peach',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: 300,
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue', flexGrow: 1}}>{message}</Text>
      <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
    </View>
```

short text case

> [image: short text case]

middle text case (wrong behaviour)

> [image: midle text case (wrong behaviour)]

long text case

> [image: long text case]

On Android, text-breaking logic makes the Text view width not enough to trigger `flexWrap` logic (see 2nd case), to move the green view bellow, it doesn't fill full width even when a lot of text inside because of line breaking.

What should I do to make it consistent for all 3 cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              backgroundColor: "peach",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              width: 300,
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "powderblue", width: "100%" }}>
              Multiline snacbar message and looooooooooong
            </Text>
            <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: "green" }} />
          </View>
```

Comment: Not correct.

You tried it? Now the green view always below, I need it only when two lines of Text reached. Try to reduce text to "Multiline snacbar"

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @JeremyCaney this is not correct answer. I explained in comment above

Comment: @amillionstarflakes: That might be true. But the contributor explaining their answer _might_ explain what they are thinking—or validate what you're response is. Regardless of whether or not their answer is correct, they should strive to provide an explanation of their thinking.